# How to set remote url when web app is running as a service in .net core (2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have deployed the `.net core(2.2)` web application as windows service but not able to access this application from remote PC.

Application is running properly With Url = "`http://localhost:5000`" on the local machine.

I have specified the Url = "`http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:5000`" with IP address in "launchSettings.json" file but not able to access it from remote PC.

For testing purpose, I have turned off my firewall setting but it does not have any effect.

Web Application Deploy environment: Windows7

**Existing source code:**

*launchSetting.json*

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56032",
      "sslPort": 44324
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TestApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));
    if (isService)
    {
            var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(pathToContentRoot);
    }

    var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray());
    var host = builder.Build();

    if (isService)
        host.RunAsService();
    else
        host.Run();
}
```

Expected Result:
Able to access .net core web application installed as web service from remote PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add **UseUrls()** here:

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    // allow remote connections
    webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000");
})
```

and also make a rule for port 5000 in Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open inbound port in Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security -> Inbound Rules -> New Rule -> Port?
[image: Open port]